# GCC can't optimize delegated lambda function involving member function pointers

Tags: c++, gcc

I compiled following c++14 code with GCC4.9.2 and clang3.6.0.
I used -O3 flag.

```
#include <utility>

struct S
{
    int a;
    int A () const { return a; }
};

template <class F, class ... Args>
int Func (F && f, Args && ... args)
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
}

using PtrA = int (S::*)() const;

int F (S const & s, PtrA ptr) { return (s.*ptr)() * 5; }

int p (S const & s) { return s.A() * 5; }

int P1 (S const & s) { return Func(&F, s , &S::A); }
int P2 (S const & s) { return Func([](S const & s, auto f) { return (s.*f)() * 5; }, s, &S::A); }
int P3 (S const & s) { return ([](S const & s, auto f) { return (s.*f)() * 5; })(s, &S::A); }
int P4 (S const & s) { return Func([](S const & s) { return s.A() * 5; }, s); }
```

`Func` calls delegated function object with passing arguments to the function object.

`P1`, `P2`, `P3` and `P4` works same as `p` with different ways.
`P1` delegates `F` which is the function involving member function pointer (`PtrA`).
`P2` delegates the lambda function which works same as `F`.
`P3` calls the lambda function directly.
`P4` calls the other lambda function without using member function pointer.

objdump of this code with GCC is

```
// p, P1, P3, P4
mov    (%rdi),%eax
lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%eax
retq   


// P2
sub    $0x8,%rsp
callq  49 <_Z2P2RK1S+0x9> // this address points to "add" in the next line.
add    $0x8,%rsp
lea    (%rax,%rax,4),%eax
retq
```

For `p`, `P1`, `P3`, `P4`, GCC outputs good code.
Oddly, for `P2`, GCC outputs bad code apparently.

On the other hand, clang outputs

```
// p, P1, P2, P3, P4
imul   $0x5,(%rdi),%eax
retq
```

Although this is no so good, outputs are same for all functions at least.

My question is whether there is the right reason that GCC can't optimize this i.e. there is the difference as C++ program between `p` and `P1` - `P4`.

If the answer to the first question is NO, is this known bug in GCC optimizer?

This question is motivated by [a Japanese article](http://qiita.com/aokomoriuta/items/517bf29f0cb62940fb31)

Comment: GCC 5+ [performs the optimization](https://goo.gl/bG5ySH) as you expect.

Comment: Oh ... I should have checked that. Thanks. I will accept your answer if you make this as answer.

Comment: Finally, I [found](https://goo.gl/dFl3am) that just adding a constant reference to a pointer in function parameters interrupts inlining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that GCC 5 and onwards is in fact capable of that optimization, see [gcc.godbolt.org](https://goo.gl/bG5ySH):

```
P2(S const&):
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    lea eax, [rax+rax*4]
    ret
```